# Recovering your Microsoft Flight Simulator X CD Key

Tags: flight-simulator-x

I had purchased and installed Microsoft Flight Simulator X Deluxe on my machine, but uninstalled it since I never used to play it all that much. Now I want to reinstall it, but I have the Disks but not the Key stickers. I've lost those. Is there any way to recover my CD Key? Does Windows 7 store the CD Key anywhere like in the registery or elsewhere from where I can get it back. Anything else I can do?

Answer (score 2):

You may contact Microsoft store with a purchase proof and *maybe* they provide you the keys. Is not a sure method (most stores doesn't allow you to re-download/re-licence content for robbery or lost) but it worth a shot.

Remember to always backup your keys in a secure place, twice.

Answer (score 1):

One resource that you can use to find your lost key is [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html). It will basically scan your computer for all the programs that you have installed and shows them in a detailed profile. This includes any CD keys that you have entered in to your computer. The website can be found [here](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html), *however* it is somewhat complicated to read at first glance, so don't expect it to be a cake walk.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not show the CD Key I used for FSX :-(